# how to specify the RXJS files needed for an Angular2 app

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I'm getting started with an Angular2 app.  My very simple Angular2 app is very slow to load.  I noticed a lot of different RXJS files are initially loaded.  Are all of these RXJS files needed?  Is there a way to limit what RXJS files get loaded?  My Angular 2 app is getting all of the related RXJS files from node_modules.  What's the best way to optimize RXJS?

Here is my app.component file:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component
 ({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
 })

export class AppComponent
{
}
```

here is my system.config.js:

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global)
{
 // map tells the System loader where to look for things
 var map =
  {
   'app': '', // 'dist',
   '@angular': '/lib/@angular',
   'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/lib/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
   'gitana': '/lib/gitana/gitana.min.js',
   'rxjs': '/lib/rxjs'
  };

 // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
 var packages =
  {
   'app': { main: 'app/main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
   'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
   'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

 var ngPackageNames =
  [
   'common',
   'compiler',
   'core',
   'forms',
   'http',
   'platform-browser',
   'platform-browser-dynamic',
   'router',
   'router-deprecated',
   'upgrade',
  ];

 // Individual files (~300 requests):
 function packIndex(pkgName)
 {
  packages[ '@angular/' + pkgName ] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
 }

 // Bundled (~40 requests):
 function packUmd(pkgName)
 {
  packages[ '@angular/' + pkgName ] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
 }

 // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
 var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

 // Add package entries for angular packages
 ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

 var config =
  {
   map: map,
   packages: packages
  };

 System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Comment: can you please share your `app.component.ts` and `system.config.js` file ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a small angular app created here. Hope it will help you to get a head start on things. Hope it will help

> https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet

Moreover, on `RxJs` you can load **individual** components, only those which you need. As you can see in this file **[rxjs-operators.ts](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/blob/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp/app/rxjs-operators.ts)**.

Instead of importing all the operators like in this statment `import 'rxjs/Rx';`. You can only load those you need.

For example:

- import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
- import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

These will only load .toPromise() and .map() operator leaving else as it is

Comment: thanks for the response.  How do you prevent systemjs from loading all RXJS files?

Comment: your files are not pre loading. system.js just maps in order to retrieve them later if they are referenced. like this line `'rxjs': '/lib/rxjs'` just tells the compiler if someone writes `import { component } from 'rxjs'` then you will use `/lib/rxjs` path. There is no loading involved. loading is only done when import statement is involved.

Comment: statments like `import 'rxjs/Rx'` OR `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'` will load components

Comment: I've removed all import 'rxjs/Rx' calls and zone.js is still loading all RXJS related files when the app first loads in browser.  I've also tried deleting all RXJS files altogether and zone.js still attempts to load every RXJS file.

Comment: try removing `'rxjs': '/lib/rxjs'` this from system.config. and check if it is loading file ?

Comment: I removed 'rxjs': '/lib/rxjs' from system.config and all files are still being loaded, however, they cannot be found

Comment: I think zone.js is dependent on RxJS. Try removing `zone.js` reference from index.html file. and see if your application starts

Comment: I tried removing zone.js as well.  if zone.js is absent, then system.src.js takes over and tries to load all RXJS files.

Comment: after much debugging, I found @angular/platform-browser//bundles/platform-browser.umd.js requires 4 different RXJS files.  3 of which do not exist.  How do you handle situation where @angular is requiring RXJS?  this leads me to the conclusion that all RXJS is required.  I'm using Angular2 version 2.0.0-rc.4.   /platform-browser.umd.js is just 1 file with RXJS requirements.  There are a lot more that are requiring different RXJS inclusions.